# How to extend an object literal class with Ecmascript 6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, nodes, javascript-objects

I have a base `class` defined as an `object literal`, with methods defined inside constructor's scope. Like this:

```
var NodeMappingAbstract = function NodeMappingAbstract() {

    this.mapToContent = function (obj) {
        throw new Error('Not implemented');
    };

    this.getInfo = function (data) {
        throw new Error('Not implemented');
    };

    this.normalizeUri = function normalizeUri(uri) {
        return uriNormalizer.normalize(uri);
    };
};
```

How do I extend the`NodeMappingAbstract` with ES6 `class` syntax? I attempted using `extends` and `super()`:

```
class SomeMapping  extends  NodeMappingAbstract{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }

    mapToContent(rawElement) {
        console.warn('mapContent called');
        return rawElement;
    }
}
```

But when I instantiate it and call `mapToContent` like this:

```
let m = new SomeMapping();
m.mapToContent();
```

I get `Error: Not implemented`, which means the implementation of the `NodeMappingAbstract` is used.

Comment: I don't see any object literal in your code?

Comment: @Bergi By `object literal` I meant the way `NodeMappingAbstract` defines methods (as instance properties). Is there a better way to call this pattern?

Comment: It's called a "constructor function with privileged methods". Or just "instance-specific methods" (doesn't really matter where they are created).

Comment: @Bergi Thanks! I have to learn a lot about javascript vacabulary :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put your methods on the prototype of your ES5 class (as you always should).

If you define them in the constructor, and create them as instance properties (which shadow anything inherited from the prototype), you will have to do the same when overwriting them:

```
class SomeMapping  extends  NodeMappingAbstract{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.mapToContent = function(rawElement) {
            console.warn('mapContent called');
            return rawElement;
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that you are attaching the methods directly on an instance of `NodeMappingAbstract` (`this`), and not the `prototype` of the function.

When JavaScript performs a lookup for an object property it first inspects the objects immediate own properties, which are what are made available when you assign something to `this`. Only if it does not find that property immediately available in this way will it turn to the `prototype`. So, although you are extending the `NodeMappingAbstract` and defining methods on the `prototype` (via the `class` sugar), you are not actually overriding the properties that are assigned to `this` on instantiation inside `NodeMappingAbstract`.

So, move the method declarations outside of the function body and onto its `prototype`:

```
var NodeMappingAbstract = function NodeMappingAbstract () {};

NodeMappingAbstract.prototype.mapToContent = function (obj) {
   throw new Error('Not implemented');
};

NodeMappingAbstract.prototype.getInfo = function (data) {
    throw new Error('Not implemented');
};

NodeMappingAbstract.prototype.normalizeUri = function normalizeUri (uri) {
    return uriNormalizer.normalize(uri);
};
```

Comment: Doesn't matter whether they are enumerable or not here :-)

Comment: @Bergi Ah! Thanks!

Comment: Thank's for the explanation! I think I cannot refactor the `NodeMappingAbstract`, I am working in a larger code base, very polluted by strange patterns

Comment: @JanOsch Then you should take a look at Bergi's answer and overwrite the methods on `this` within the constructor :-)